# why the Push() function in my Linked List implementation shows this behaviour?

Tags: c, pointers

I wrote a Push() function to push an element inside a linked list.
Below is the code, I wrote first :

```
struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

void Push(struct node*, int);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    struct node *list = NULL;

    Push(list, 23);

    return 0;
}

void Push(struct node *list, int data) {
    struct node *newNode;

    newNode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->next = list;
    list = newNode;

}
```

The code compiles well and executes as well but then no matter how many numbers I push on the List, the changes doesn't reflect and the list remains empty.

Then I created the function the other way and used double pointer like this:

```
struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

void Push(struct node**, int);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    struct node *list = NULL;

    Push(&list, 23);

    return 0;

}

void Push(struct node **list, int data) {
    struct node *newNode;

    newNode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->next = *list;
    *list = newNode;
}
```

Here the code worked well and pushed the element on the list and the change reflected as well.

so, Why does it show such a different behaviour, even though I did a small test and found that both

```
*list
```

and

```
 list
```

contains the same address. Here is what I did for the test:

```
struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};


void CheckAddress1(struct node *list) {
    printf("Address1 is: %p\n", list);
}

void CheckAddress2(struct node **list) {
    printf("Address3 is: %p\n", *list);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    struct node *list = NULL;

    CheckAddress1(list);
    CheckAddress2(&list);

    return 0;
}
```

and the output was

```
Address1 is: (nil)
Address3 is: (nil)
```

This is because both are pointing towards same location.
So it means both should work. Then why the different working.Can you guys elaborate? Thanks

Comment: You are confusing yourself by having two variables (one in `main` and one in `Push`) that are both called `list`. If you give them different names, your confusion will go away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`list` in `main()` has the address of the first element of the list. `*list` gives the content in the memory location pointed to by `list`.

In your first program, you are passing `list` to `Push()` by value. That means the `list` in `Push()` is merely a copy of `list` in `main()` and any modifications made to `list` of `Push()` is *not* reflected back to the one in `main()`.

In the second program, you are passing a pointer to `list` in `main()` as argument to `Push()` and in `Push()` you manipulate the value at the memory location pointed to by this pointer so that you are effectively modifying the `list` in `main()`.

Hence the changes you make in `Push()` are reflected back to `main()` for program 2 but not for program 1.